# iOS app link usage in app for sharing detail about an app, which is still pending Apple's review, will Apple allow this?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

when I completed itunes connect app process (status is waiting for review) , itunes connect shows the app link in "links" section.

I am going to upload app first version (not yet any earlier version to Appstore) to Apple app store ,but i want to show the same app itunes link in my app (which is I am uploading) itself for share app link via email(body text) functionality but app is not yet ready for sale.

(Once app will approve,same link can work for download) ? 
Is apple allow this and will approve app if I am doing like this ?

Comment: the link uses the app id, make sure the app id shown in the link is the same as the one registered in your itunes connect account. As long as you don't delete this app from the itunes connect, the link will work when the app is published.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns App Store policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an absolutely normal thing. I have implemented that for asking the user to rate my own games and apps. When the app was submitted, the links didn't work, of course. They were accepted and when each app went live it would allow rating by the user.
I also have experience with "gift this app" links: no problem.